# Java: Unable to search properly through an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

So i created this board using two dimensional array and then i wanna check through it to see if it has any ship S on it. However, my array looks at each row and column and since the ship is only at a certain position NOT the entire table, it prints out "No ship found" How do i fix this? Please help!

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class bord {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String Board[][]= new String[4][4];
            int n=0;
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    Board[i][j]="-";

                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    System.out.print(Board[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("_______________");

                 //from here!

            Board[1][1]="S";
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    if(!Board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
                    {

                        n=1;
                    }
                }

            }
            if(n==1)
            {
                System.out.println("No ship found");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Found it");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the variable `n` is constantly being overwritten for each check of `Board[i][j]`.

So although `n = 1` when checking `Board[1][1]`, it will be overwritten immediately after when checking `Board[1][2]` so eventually `n = 0`.

I would recommend changing the following code to this:

```
//from here!

Board[1][1]="S";
boolean isShipFound = false; //Variable to keep track if the ship has been found.
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        if(Board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            isShipFound = true;
            break; //Exits the j loop.
        }
    }
    if (isShipFound)
    {
        break; //Exits the i loop.
    }

}
if(!isFound)
{
    System.out.println("No ship found");
}
else
    System.out.println("Found it");
}
```

Comment: yea what should i do :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I believe that you are just having a small logic problem here.

So, what you are doing, is if the element isn't S, you say no ship found. If your entire 2D array was filled with S, this would work, and if there was not one S, it would work. However, if you took out the not in your `if` statement, and change what the bottom `if` statements do, it would work perfectly. I'll demonstrate:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class bord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Board[][]= new String[4][4];
        int n=0;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                Board[i][j]="-";

            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(Board[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("_______________");

             //from here!

        Board[1][1]="S";
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                if(Board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("S"))//I changed this line
                {

                    n=1;
                }
            }

        }
        if(n==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Found it");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No ship found");
    }

}
```

If an s is found, then it sets n to 1, but if there is not one s, it never sets n to 1, and therefore, recognizes, that there is no s. I hope that you find this helpful and I wish you luck! :)

Comment: Like the other answers suggested, it's Java - instead of `int n=0` use `boolean isFound = false` and then in the nested `for` add it to the condition: `for (int i=0; i<4 && !isFound; i++)` to both `for`s. Just better coding, and more efficient algorithm.

Comment: True. My goal was to just show the OP the logic error. Put one foot in front of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Change below logic in your code :

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                if (Board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {

                    n = 1;
                }
            }

        }
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.println("Found it");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No ship found");
        }
```

value of **n** is 0 initially and when you are checking for **S** in inner loop it was making **n=1** for every non matching condition and as the last position of your array was holding **-** so it will make **n=1** and that's why you were getting wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Board[1][1]="S";
outer:
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    for(int j=0; j < 4; j++)
    {
      if(Board[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
      {
          System.out.println("Ship found");
          break outer;
      }
      else if(i == 3 && j == 3)
      {
          System.out.println("Ship not found");
      }
    }
}
```